# Convert an image (png/jpeg) to multipart object in iOS

Tags: ios, uiimage, multipart

I have an app thats needs to connect to a backend server. The Java developer tells me the app must send an image as a multipart object. I've spent hours searching the web for information on converting images to multipart files in ios but I've found nothing useful. I have no prior knowledge of multipart also.

Could someone post a sample code or point me in the right direction/necessary steps involved? Or share any knowledge that they may have in regards to sending  images as multipart objects.

Sorry I hope this isnt a bit vague and I can supply more information if needed.

-the server uses json

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using something like [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking), which has a http client class that can take care of the multipart data upload for you.

```
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"upload/" 
               parameters:nil 
constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
        [formData appendPartWithFileData:yourData 
                                    name:@"attachment" 
                                fileName:@"attachment.jpg" 
                                mimeType:@"image/jpg"];
    }];
```

Comment: Evidently constructing multipart HTML is quite complicated, and even the slightest misuse of a newline character will render it unreadable. I once tried to get a multipart form to work in code, but failed, and in the end the AFNetworking framework handled it just fine. You could probably read the source for that framework and get it to work in code yourself, if you're willing to work at it for a few days.

Comment: Im not sure if AFNetworking is a good option, the developer has left and has suggested finding libraries than AFNetworking.

Comment: Are you sure?  I haven't seen that.  Do you have a link?  Are you perhaps talking about ASIHTTPRequest and not AFNetworking?  As far as I can tell, the AFNetworking github is still active.  The main developer committed just yesterday actually.